# Taking css property from one html page to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just wondering is there any way to take a CSS property from one page to another page.

Let me describe briefly - I am have two webpages, called `one.html` and `two.html`.
In `one.html` there is a button called `darkview`. If the user clicks on the button then  `one.html`'s background colour will change.

In the same page I have a link. When the user clicks that, it will go to the second page (`two.html`). But now the problem is: I have changed the background colour in one.html, I want that also apply to second page. So how take that property and apply to the second page?

[Here are a few lines code I have written](http://jsfiddle.net/mnaresh/GL9wt/1/).

(Problem can be solved by using JavaScript or jQuery.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this helps. You can use sessionStorage for temprory clientSide storage. If you want to persist the values, you can uses localStorage

One.html

```
<form>
     <input type="button" value="darkview" id="newColor"  />
</form>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var color = document.getElementById('newColor');
    color.onclick = function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ddd';
        window.sessionStorage['currentColor'] = '#ddd';
    }
}
</script>

Two.html

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var color = window.sessionStorage['currentColor'];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`localStorage`](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or [`sessionStorage`](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) to keep settings on browser level, or you can have session on the web server that can keep current state.

Http is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), which means that it cannot remember previous state or request, this is why session is created, or on client side, local storage, sessionStorage or even cookies. Simply save state to variable in `localStorage` and retrieve it on `pageLoad`.

Comment: ok.I am still not familiar with localStorage. Is there any way using JavaScript location object.

Comment: Then get familiar with it, it doesn't get simpler than that

Comment: Also I'd recommend `sessionStorage` rather than `localStorage` unless the data is important enough to keep for prolonged time

Comment: @Kos, agreed! Use sessionStorage for simple state transfer!

Comment: thanks friends for all of your suggestion. I will learn this technique. and I will apply to my mobile project.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cookies to store the state and simple check if cookie exists and what the value is.
Is there no cookie, switch do default.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
function checkCookie()
{
var theme=getCookie("theme");
  if (theme!=null && theme!="")
  {
  setTheme(theme);
  }
else 
  {
  theme="light";
  if (theme!=null && theme!="")
    {
    setCookie("theme",theme,365);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think using this method also we can do it. But I am a fresher in javascript. so, for me it is littlebit difficult to understand.

Comment: All you have to do is edit the code in checkcookie and write a piece of javascript with the function setTheme("themename"){} that sets a cookie using setCookie() and then applies the theme.
Default theme is "light";