# Send value from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 pages say  index.html and 2ndPage.html. 
index.html has two textboxes and a button. Now i want to enter some data in the textboxes and received the data in 2ndpage.html. I want to use only javascript. dont want to use query string. Only post or get method. Is it possible? Please help me or guide me how to send and receive data form one page to another in javascript/jquery.

Comment: can't i do this without php? please help me. i want to use only javascript. is it possible?

Comment: you can get it by post method in php. why do you want do it by JS?

Comment: is it mandatory to use php if i use get or post method. I want some code. any appropriate link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to know the difference between the usase of server-side and client side programming. And the ways how data can be passed. Without any control you cannot really pass data. so read about it

Comment: You can use cookies, but why are you limiting yourself in the first place? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using localStorage or sessionStorage you can do this. here is a link, which will help you. i just take few css property from one page to another page. but you can take input value also.
[Taking css property from one html page to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683248/taking-css-property-from-one-html-page-to-another-page)

or if you are taking care of old browser also then javascript Location object is the way to go.

Comment: thank you very much naresh. will you please provide the code without the session storage? actually session  storage is a HTML5 property. But i just want to use the basic. Is it possible?

Comment: ok. if you are not familiar with these, then you can do this using old method like save a cookie and next page retrieve it. try this. same link only you will get cookie reference also.

Answer (score 2):

Well, using javascript or jquery you can accomplish that. Check jQuery's [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. Otherwise, learn PHP as already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: even AJAX would require a server side language like PHP or ASP

Comment: well not really. If you use GET then you have the query string (though the question tells us that qs is not preferred), which means you can parse it with JS and get the required strings. Although I'd recommend using a server side language, this is quite possible with javascript.